# Why do we Need to Write ".class" in Synchronized Blocks

Tags: java, multithreading, syntax

In Java, when writing synchronized code blocks with a class monitor, we need the write `.class` to specify that it is a class monitor and not an instance. Why do we need to write that? It's easy for other programmers to tell that it's a class because of the title case, does it help the compiler somehow?

Here is an example:

```
void someMethod() {
    synchronized (SomeClass.class) {
        // do something
    }
}
```

Why can't we just write `synchronized(SomeClass) { ... }`?

Comment: Because that's the syntax.  `SomeClass` is basically just a namespace, you have to specify what you want in that namespace.

Comment: Aside: synchronizing on the class itself is very unusual.  Are you sure this design is correct?

Comment: You could certainly use an instance to synchronize on. Or refactor the code to use [`ReentrantLock`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantLock.html) instead. What exactly is the problem?

Comment: Oh you're totally right about the namespace, I don't know why it didn't occur to me. I have just been learning about multithreading, I haven't used it yet. I could imagine synchronizing the class could be useful for working with static field, but what do I know.

Comment: Is there a way to resolve the question without putting an answer there, or should I just delete it? since it's pretty much a simple misinterpretation on my part

Comment: Because static fields are effectively global variables, the lock is effectively global also.  This can be bad for performance.  C.f. (Amdal's Law.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amdahl%27s_law)

Comment: Classes don't _have_ to be named in title case, it's just convention.

Comment: @JohnSmith Feel free to delete it, or if you think it may be helpful to another user just leave it and it will age away over time or be voted closed.

Comment: In Java it is legal to have variables named same as class like `String String = "String";`. When you write `synchronized(String){..}` it would NOT synchronize on string *class* but on that *variable*.

Answer (score 1):

> Why do we need to write that?

Because the Java language syntax requires you to use `.class`.

Specifically the syntax requires an expression at that point, and a class identifier is not a valid expression.  (Technically, the name of a class is in a different namespace to the names of variables / fields and methods, and the only identifiers that can be used like that are variable / field identifiers.)

> It's easy for other programmers to tell that it's a class because of the title case, does it help the compiler somehow?

Not at all.  As far as the Java language and Java compilers are concerned, title case conveys no special meaning.

Note that the Java compiler allows people to get away with egregious style errors in identifier naming.  As far as the JLS is concerned, the following is valid Java:

```
// I choose to ignore style conventions to annoy my coworkers
public class vile_class {
    private int Vile_Field;
    // ... 
}
```

Therefore no Java compiler can infer that the name `Vile_Field` refers to a class or `vile_class` refers to a field.

---

If they had designed the Java grammar so that you could use a class name as an expression (i.e. referring to the `.class` object), that *could* have lead to ambiguity in the grammar.  It would also have introduced a new kind of obscure compilation error.  Anyway, the issue is *moot*.  The Java language is what it is.